# How can i add new rdp connections after installing no auth extension in apache guacamole?

Tags: apache, guacamole

I have installed 0.9.14 version of guacamole which provides the interface to login and adding new connections. I want to give the new machine connection links to users so, that they can access the machines without login.

For that, I have installed no auth extension in that for bypassing the login but now I am not able to add a new connection and delete previous connections.

Please Suggest some good to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring noauth didn't you have to edit:

/etc/guacamole/user-mappings.xml

I think you just add more connections in that file.